# Import React ,{Component} from 'react'

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I encountered a problem that import React. This is my error

[image]

Maybe it is a normal problem and I also find some ways to solve the problem on Google. I can't solve problem now.Because I think I already has changed it.This is my code
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: I see you already forget to import AppRegistry, try to import it and build again. And your format is corrected.

Comment: @Nguyên Hoàng Thanks, I fixed it but it doesn't work

Comment: try to upgrade React Native' version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: have you install any react-native module. if so than check their index.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import * as React from 'react';


class MyProject extends React.Component ...
```